# Html view file is not loading from its controller GET Action method

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to view the report from the button click event of another view file. I have two html file. One is 'FleetSummary' view and another is 'FleetDetailed' View.
From the Summary view ,If I click the button  I am re-directing to the same controller method 'FleetDetailedReport' in 'FleetCheckController' from its Javascript func  calling from button click event of SummaryView. But controller method 'FleetDetailedReport' is working fine but the view is not loading. I can see the pointer is passing to the view but not loading to dom. Here is the code.

In Summary html

```
<button type="button" name="submitAll" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"
        onclick="ListFleets()">
        View Detailed Report
</button>
function ListFleets() {
        var code = "@Model.CustomerCode";
        var datefrom = "@Model.FromDate";
        var dateto = "@Model.ToDate";       
        var regno = '';
        var selectedRows = table.rows('.selected').nodes(); // get an array of the selected row nodes
        $(selectedRows).each(function() {            
            regno = table.cell(this, 2).data();
        })        
       
        var url = '@Url.Action("FleetDetailedReport","FleetCheck")';
         $.ajax({
             url: url,
            type: "GET",
            data:{
                CustomerCode: code,
                datefrom: datefrom,
                dateto: dateto,
                regno: regno                
            },
            success: function (response) {            
            },
            error: function (response) {
                var misinfo = ('@ViewBag.Result');                
            }
        });         
    }

FleetCheck Controller
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FleetDetailedReport(string CustomerCode, string datefrom, string dateto, string regno)
{
    return View();
}
```

In Detailed html

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="VehicleReport">
    <div class="row">
    <form asp-controller="FleetCheck"
    asp-action="FleetDetailedReport"
    data-ajax="true"
    data-ajax-method="GET"
    data-ajax-mode="replace" 
    data-ajax-update="#content"
    class="form-horizontal"
    role="form"
    data-parsley-validate novalidate
    id="frmDetail">
    <label class="control-label-left padding-left-twenty col-sm-6" for="field1"> REPORT  </label>
   </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your  defintion of `table` ?

Comment: Add a`<div id="content"></div>` in your Summary html, and with below answer add `$('#content').html(response);`in success function , then it will show Detailed html in  Summary html.